# Announcing a “Graduation” election for 2023

Tags: discussion, election

**Summary**: Stellar Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [an election](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/election/1) on **February 28**, as your “graduation” election.

The timeline:

- On February 21, I'll post a question collection post on Meta, so that the community can post questions they'd like to see the candidates answer.
- Starting on February 28, users can [nominate themselves](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/election/1). The top questions collected on the previous week will be compiled into a questionnaire on the election page, so that potential moderators can answer them.
- The existing moderator team will need to run in the election if they wish to keep their positions.
- On March 7, if there are 4 or more candidates, the election will move into the voting phase. If not, we'll extend the nomination period for a week. If, at the end of that extension period, there are still fewer than 4 candidates, we'll simply appoint the candidates who've nominated (and aren't already pro-tem mods), and we'll default to considering this a "pro-tem election" just to try to bring the total number of moderators on the site up to 3 (for full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections)). (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year).)
- If the election moves into the voting phase, I'll announce the results on Meta on March 15 (or March 22, if we need to extend the nomination period).

If you have any questions about the process, please post them in an answer here.

Comment: No candidates so far :( I'm not an SME on Stellar - just a curious SE user with a few posts. If you need another janitor, I'll write a short nomination, indicating just this. I mean, I surely can check in on the site once per day and close blatantly off-topic questions, deal with spam, approve copy edits, etc.

Comment: @Glorfindel:. You would be welcome to step forward.  We work together on Lifehacks, why not here too?

Comment: @Chenmunka thank you, I posted a nomination. At the same time, it would be good to have at least one subject matter expert on board.